# Store table int ids into an int[] attribute of a ViewModel class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to pull all `int` Ids from a joint table's column and have it stored in an attribute of a ViewModel class.

Note: `Categorisation` is a mapped table of `Foo` and `Bar` entity classes. I'm filtering only `Id`s of `Foo` in this case.

```
var model = _ctx.FooDbSet.Where(y => y.Id == x.Id).Select(x => new FooManageVM
        {
            // ... other attributes here

            CategorisationIds = _ctx.CategorisationDbSet.Where(w => w.Foo.Id == id).Select(s => s.Foo.Id).ToArray()

        }).Single();
```

Although there's the `.ToArray()` method at the end (`.ToArray<int>()` also doesn't work), I'm getting this error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32[] ToArray[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I tried extracting the query to the above, like:

```
var ids = _ctx.CategorisationDbSet.Where(w => w.Foo.Id == id).Select(s => s.Foo.Id);
```

then below:

```
// this is of type int[]
CategorisationIds = ids.ToArray()
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using an older version of EF (< 6?).  I'm not sure you need the .ToArray() call.  Have you tried it without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do is change the type of CategorisationsIds to `IEnumerable<int>`.

Also, check that you reference System.Linq

But if that doesn't work you could query an anonymous object and instantiate the FooManageVM with the result from .Single():

```
var result = _ctx.FooDbSet.Where(y => y.Id == x.Id).Select(x => 
    {
        // ... other attributes here

        CategorisationIds = _ctx.CategorisationDbSet.Where(w => w.Foo.Id == id).Select(s => s.Foo.Id)

    }).Single();

var model = new FooManageVM {
     // ... other attributes here
     CategorisationIds = result.CategorisationIds.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm using this attribute for storing `multiple selectlist` selected items so I guess I have to stick with `int[]` type

Comment: If it is an IEnumerable. Then you would just call .ToArray() when you bind to the control.

Comment: It works (I removed the previous comment - I had a nasty flaw in my code, which pulled Foo ids, instead of Bar ids for select list)

Answer (score 0):

Move the `.ToArray()` call outside of the main query

Try:

```
var ids = _ctx.CategorisationDbSet.Where(w => w.Foo.Id == id).Select(s => s.Foo.Id).ToArray();
```

then:

```
CategorisationIds = ids;
```

Comment: Now the error is: `The array type 'System.Int32[]' cannot be initialized in a query result. Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.Int32] instead.`

Comment: ok - did you try that suggestion?  Rather than `.ToArray()` use `.ToList()`

Comment: `var ids = _ctx.CategorisationDbSet.Where(w => w.Foo.Id == id).Select(s => s.Foo.Id).ToList();`

Answer (score -2):

Use ToList() at first:

```
.Select(s => s.Foo.Id).ToList().ToArray()
```

When you use ToList the records fetched from DB and ready as a linq object.

Comment: Just tested - I'm afraid this change didn't do anything.

Comment: @developer10 What is the error? Are you sure you have a value on DB?